# Route to custom file

Tags: themes, routing

I would like to create a custom file inside an existing WordPress theme. But I'm not sure how to route to it, and tell WordPress that the route named `www.mysite.com/custom` should redirect to the `custom.php` file inside my theme's directory.

Comment: You can create a [Custom Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates) and apply it to your WordPress page at `/custom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just simple. First create a page and use slug for it as `custom`. And then rename you php file to `page-custom.php` and that would be it.